# image transmission through waveguides

Tags: optics

in general optics we study the transmission of image information through lenses, basically governed by Fourier optics laws. how can images be transmitted through waveguides at smaller propagation distances? 
(the question is in context to the use of waveguides in photonic circuits)
what i wanted to ask was that is it possible to set up a system that would allow the transmission and subsequent recording at a later distance using waveguides.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question.  Lenses don't "transmit" images:  they convert phase information at the lens to intensity information at the image plane (roughly speaking).

Whether in free space or a waveguide, the wavefront propagation is such that there's no image of the source object except at specific distances from focussing elements.   Photonic circuits merely transmit the energy from one place to another  without loss (no light escapes the waveguide) but there's no maintenance of the  image properties.

Answer (score 0):

A waveguide cannot directly transmit a whole image--it gets scrambled beyond recognition even if all the light passes through.

What you can do is form an image at the entrance to a bundle of waveguides, then each waveguide carries one pixel, so you still have an image at the other end. Analogous to an endoscope.